# How to unlink a subtask in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I specified one issue A as a subtask of issue B in JIRA.  In reality it is not a subtask but a separate issue.  How to remove issue A as a subtask of issue B leaving the issue A as a separate issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert your sub-task to a standard issue through convert to issue under the more dropdown menu.

Here is a link to the atlassian documentation about it: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/creating-a-sub-task-720416196.html

Comment: Yes, I just did this, found myself

Comment: If this is a solution for finding yourself, you should crosspost it to Philosophy StackExchange! ;)